# QGIS Style Manager's tag entries - how to make use of them when accessing color ramps

Tags: qgis, style, style-manager

I've found a lot of pre-defined QGIS-style XML files on the web. Importing them into the QGIS-internal style repository was easy as expected, and labeling by specifying meaningful tag-entries was applied within a second.

However, when trying to access the massive number of imported and tagged styles from "Layer Styling / Color ramp" list, there is a huge sequential list of color ramps sorted by name.

Is there a way of making use of the tag-concept within the map-design process when trying to choose styles from the color-ramp dropdown menu?